# First run after a year...what next?

Tags: running, weight-loss

I decided yesterday to get back into running and ran as I felt comfortable for as long as possible until I couldn't anymore. The thing that caused me to stop was my fitness being so poor as opposed to my muscles giving in.

I ran 2 miles which aren't great but it's been a long time so I had no idea what to expect. I ran my first mile in 6:11 and ended up doing 2.08 miles in 15:47.

Today I am quite sore, my thighs ache and walking is a bit uncomfortable because of it. But I really want to start running as much as possible and get my times down, run for longer and improve my fitness.

I weigh 143lbs (65kg) and I am 5'10 (178cm) tall but I want to lose 11lbs (5kg) because I have a bit of excess weight around my stomach - not much - but I don't have much definition there as I used to.

I was hoping to run every day after work for the foreseeable future but my soreness is something I suppose I didn't anticipate.

Is it wise to run whilst sore? I guess my body is getting used to running again but what should I do in the interim whilst they are repairing? I am really keen to improve my fitness and lose weight.

Comment: There is no real definitive measure of exercise with DOMS, it's very individual. However, I'm curious as to why you want to be 132 lbs at 5'10"?

Answer (score 1):

What was your pace when you used to run regularly?  How far?

It seems pretty obvious that you went way to hard for your first outing.  The difference is pace is great between your first and second mile.  The key would be to slow down, run slower with more breaks.

If it was me, I would follow the couch to 5k program.  It is free on most mobile platforms and you run three times per week.

Your interest in fat loss, at a pretty low weight for your height may require some special research in how to burn fat.  Part of it will be exercise, but also diet.  What are you putting in your body that is unhealthy?  The last thing you want to do is burn the little muscle you have (based on weight) that often occurs while running at very high intensities.

You are better off staying below the lactate threshold (probably about around a 9 min/mile pace for you) and doing so for long distances.  (Around 5 miles or more.)